# Application-defined or object-defined error using Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba, vcf-vcard

I am trying to create my own VCard and then convert that to a QR Code. The VCard and QR Code generate perfectly until I added in my line for the addition of the photo. I have converted my image to Base64 and followed the required syntax, yet I keep getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error".

My code is:

```
Sub generateQRCode()
    
    strURL = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr"
    
    For intRow = 2 To 2
    
        strFname = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("A" & intRow).Text)
        strLname = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("B" & intRow).Text)
        strCellPhone = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("C" & intRow).Text)
        strBusPhone = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("D" & intRow).Text)
        strEmail = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("E" & intRow).Text)
        strCompn = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("F" & intRow).Text)
        strJobTitle = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("G" & intRow).Text)
        strDept = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("H" & intRow).Text)
        strWeb = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("I" & intRow).Text)
        strAdd = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("J" & intRow).Text)
        strPht = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("K" & intRow).Text)
        
        strVCF = ""
        strVCF = strVCF & "BEGIN:VCARD" & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "VERSION:3.0" & Chr(10)
        
        strVCF = strVCF & "N:" & strLname & ";" & strFname & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "ORG:" & strCompn & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "TITLE:" & strJobTitle & " | " & strDept & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "FN:" & strFname & " " & strLname & Chr(10)
        
        strVCF = strVCF & "TEL;TYPE=CELL:" & strCellPhone & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "TEL;TYPE=WORK:" & strBusPhone & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "EMAIL:" & strEmail & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "URL:" & strWeb & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "ADR:" & strAdd & Chr(10)
        strVCF = strVCF & "PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:" & strPht
         
        strVCF = strVCF & "END:VCARD"
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("L" & intRow) = strVCF
        
        strChs = "&chs=150" & "x" & "150"
        strChl = "&chl="
        strFinalURL = strURL & strChs & strChl & strVCF
        
        Dim pic As Object, sh As Shape
        ActiveSheet.Range("M" & intRow).Select
        
        Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFinalURL)
        pic.Top = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & intRow).Top
        pic.Left = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & intRow).Left
       
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The issue is centered around the handling of the image. I know my base64 conversion is correct since I have written a basic VCard code in my Notepad and managed to get the VCard to display with the image. However, when I try this in my excel macro, I keep getting the above warning and no QR Code generates. I have no idea where the issue lies.

Comment: You mentioned that you don't know where the issue is coming from.  If you step through the code line by line, what is the last successful line that runs?  This will help us figure out what line is throwing your error.

Comment: When you get the error message, click "Debug" - which line is highlighted?

Comment: How long is your final value of `strFinalURL`?  If you have >2k characters you need to use a POST to get the image.  https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes#:~:text=Note%20that%20URLs%20have%20a%202K%20maximum%20length%2C%20so%20if%20you%20want%20to%20encode%20more%20than%202K%20bytes%20(minus%20the%20other%20URL%20characters)%2C%20you%20will%20have%20to%20send%20your%20data%20using%20POST.

Comment: Upper limit: "QR Codes store up to 4,296 alphanumeric characters of arbitrary text"

Comment: The issue is arising around the generation of the QR Code. The QR Code cannot be developed due to the value of strFinalURL being approximately 5k characters.